# Pytorch matrix multiplication

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm struggling with dimension and matric multiplication in pytorch.
I want to multiply matrix A

```
tensor([[[104.7500, 111.3750, 138.2500, 144.8750],
         [104.2500, 110.8750, 137.7500, 144.3750]],

        [[356.8750, 363.5000, 390.3750, 397.0000],
         [356.3750, 363.0000, 389.8750, 396.5000]]])
```

with matrix B

```
tensor([[[[  0.,   1.,   2.,   5.,   6.,   7.,  10.,  11.,  12.],
          [  2.,   3.,   4.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
          [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  20.,  21.,  22.],
          [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  22.,  23.,  24.]],

         [[ 25.,  26.,  27.,  30.,  31.,  32.,  35.,  36.,  37.],
          [ 27.,  28.,  29.,  32.,  33.,  34.,  37.,  38.,  39.],
          [ 35.,  36.,  37.,  40.,  41.,  42.,  45.,  46.,  47.],
          [ 37.,  38.,  39.,  42.,  43.,  44.,  47.,  48.,  49.]],

         [[ 50.,  51.,  52.,  55.,  56.,  57.,  60.,  61.,  62.],
          [ 52.,  53.,  54.,  57.,  58.,  59.,  62.,  63.,  64.],
          [ 60.,  61.,  62.,  65.,  66.,  67.,  70.,  71.,  72.],
          [ 62.,  63.,  64.,  67.,  68.,  69.,  72.,  73.,  74.]]],


        [[[ 75.,  76.,  77.,  80.,  81.,  82.,  85.,  86.,  87.],
          [ 77.,  78.,  79.,  82.,  83.,  84.,  87.,  88.,  89.],
          [ 85.,  86.,  87.,  90.,  91.,  92.,  95.,  96.,  97.],
          [ 87.,  88.,  89.,  92.,  93.,  94.,  97.,  98.,  99.]],

         [[100., 101., 102., 105., 106., 107., 110., 111., 112.],
          [102., 103., 104., 107., 108., 109., 112., 113., 114.],
          [110., 111., 112., 115., 116., 117., 120., 121., 122.],
          [112., 113., 114., 117., 118., 119., 122., 123., 124.]],

         [[125., 126., 127., 130., 131., 132., 135., 136., 137.],
          [127., 128., 129., 132., 133., 134., 137., 138., 139.],
          [135., 136., 137., 140., 141., 142., 145., 146., 147.],
          [137., 138., 139., 142., 143., 144., 147., 148., 149.]]]])
```

However using the simple `@` to multiply them, doesn'e lead me to the desired result.
What I want is somethinlg like: multiply the first two rows of A by the first 3 4x9 submatrices of B (let's say B[:,:,0,:]) so that I have two results, then in the same way muliply the third and fourth row of A with the second 3 4x9 submatrices of B, so to have again two results, then I want to sum the first results of each multiplication and the second results of each.
I know I have to work with some kind of reshapes but I find it so confusing, can you help me with a quite generalizable solution?

Comment: look at [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html?highlight=einsum#torch.einsum)

Comment: I want to do it using the matrix multiplication since it is for a project in which I'm not allowed to use torch. functions but only tensor. methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example would be helpful:

```
a = torch.ones((4, 4)).long()
a = a.reshape(2, 2, 4)
b = torch.tensor(list(range(36*6)))
b = b.reshape(2, 3, 4, 9)

t1 = a[0] @ b[0, :]
t2 = a[1] @ b[1, :]
result = t1 + t2
```

---

```
accum = torch.zeros((b.shape[1], a.shape[1], b.shape[3]))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
  accum = accum + (a[i] @ b[i, :])
```

Comment: Thanks! DO you know if there's a way to make it work for bigger sizes of the two matrices, in general more than 2 submatrices?

Comment: I added the code accumulating the result of a matric multiplication. It might cause some error since I didn't check if it is working

Answer (score 3):

In case there's someone wondering how to perform this with [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html), you just have to think in terms of dimensions and explicit the operation with the subscript:

```
>>> torch.einsum('ijk,ilkm->ljm', A, B)
```

The overall operation performed is, in pseudo-code:

```
for i, j, k, l, m in IxJxKxLxM:
    out[l][j][m] += A[i][j][k]*B[i][l][k][m]
```